# How to prove the types of coset for a given multiplicative group?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

Let $\mathbb{Z}_k^\times$ be a multiplicative group modulo $k$.
Assuming $k=2^c$ is a power of two integer (for positive int $c$), $\mathbb{Z}_k^\times$ consists of odd integers less than $k$.

Does this hold $\mathbb{Z}_k^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\frac{k}{4}}$ and how can we prove that?

Why can't we have the following isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_k^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2^a} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\frac{k}{2^{a+1}}}$ for some integer $a$?

Comment: Obviously not. $|\mathbb Z_k^\times| = \frac k 2$, $|\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_{\frac k2}| = k$. Please check the question for typos.

Comment: @player3236 Sorry. This was the typo. I fixed it. Would you mind if you check it again?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $c \ge 3$.

Note that $|\mathbb Z_k^\times| = \dfrac k2$.

Since $\mathbb Z_k^\times$ is abelian, we just need to show the following:

1. $\mathbb Z_k^\times$ is not cyclic, or equivalently, it has no element of order $\dfrac k2$;
2. $\mathbb Z_k^\times$ has an element of order $\dfrac k4$.

For 1, we know that $\mathbb Z_k^\times$ is cyclic, or equivalently, there are primitive roots mod $k$, iff $k = 2$ or $4$ or $p^n$ or $2p^n$. Therefore for $c\ge3$, $\mathbb Z_k^\times$ is not cyclic.

For 2, we need look no further than $3$. The multiplicative order of $3$ mod $k$ is equal to $\dfrac k4$. Here is a proof of this fact: [Proof $\operatorname{ord}_{2^n}(3)=2^{n-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765483/proof-operatornameord-2n3-2n-2). This also answers your second question: $a$ can only equal to $1$ since there is an element of order $\dfrac k 4$.

Now the result follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups.