# How many integers in the form $q^k$ mod by $p^d q$ for distinct prime $p$ and $q$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes, and $d$ be a positive integer.
There are only finite many (at most $p^d q$) distinct integers in the form $q^k$ with non-negative integer $k$ mod by $p^d q$.
But how many of them?

When $p=2$ and $q=3$, I have calculated for $d=1, 2, \dots, 16$, and the answer is $2, 3, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 65, \dots, 16385$.
That is, the answer seems to be $2^{d-2} +1$ for all $d$ except $1$ and $2$.

Is this true for the case $p=2$ and $q=3$? And how about for general $p$ and $q$?

Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: You can see proofs for $\operatorname{ord}_{2^n}(3)=2^{n-2}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765483/proof-operatornameord-2n3-2n-2).

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for $p=2,q=3$ is correct.

There is the solution $q^0=1$ and then there are the solutions $3^{k+1}$ modulo $2^d3$ i.e. $3^k$ modulo $2^d$.

Now the least power $3^k\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ is $k=2$.
For $d>3$, by Hensel lifting,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma

the least power  $3^k\equiv 1 \pmod {2^d}$ is $2^{d-2}$.

Hence we get $2^{d-2}+1$ solutions:
$$1,3,3^2, ...,3^{2^{d-2}}.$$

**Extension**

Other values of $p$ and $q$ can be handled in the same way - give it a go!

In fact, for $p\ne 2$ the Hensel lifting is marginally easier since you can start with the solution for  $q^k\equiv 1 \pmod p$. (For $p=2$ we needed to start at modulo $p^3$.)